# Transform all subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UIView in a scrollview that contains about 100 subviews. The subviews all look the same and are instances of the same class. I have a transform that I want to apply to each subview. But the transform needs to change everytime zoomScale changes.

What's the best way to apply the transform to all the views? Currently Im implementing layoutSubviews, getting the array of subviews, and setting each subview's transform to the new transform.

Is there an optimal way to do this?

Update:

The views I want to transform are pins on a map. When I zoom in with scrollView they need to be scaled down (i.e. so they look the same size to the user) and remain locked to the same position).

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0/self.zoomValue, 1.0/self.zoomValue);

    for(UIView *view in self.subviews){
        view.transform = transform;
    }    
}
```

...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.mapMarkerContainer.zoomValue = scrollView.zoomScale;
    [self.mapMarkerContainer setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: I call layoutSubviews everytime scrollViewDidZoom is called. Performance is a bit sluggish.

Comment: You shouldn't call `layoutSubviews` directly...

Comment: How then? needsLayout doesnt change the views often when I call that.

Comment: `You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the setNeedsLayout method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded method.` From the [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) docs

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question a few hours ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150075/rendering-a-transform-once-for-multiple-views/9150385#9150385

Comment: It's a different question if you read

Comment: @Paul.s - i have corrected my error by adding setNeedsLayout - Thanks. But my question still remains - is this the optimal way to go about laying out my subviews?

Comment: Can we see the code you use to apply the transforms?

Comment: @Paul.s - any ideas on the best way to do this in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research around this, it turns out that my initial method is the most efficient:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0/self.zoomValue, 1.0/self.zoomValue);

    for(UIView *view in self.subviews){
        view.transform = transform;
    }    
}
```

Sometimes I guess you just have to accept that there are limitations on how quick an iPhone can process data.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're applying the same transformation to *all* subviews, `CALayer`'s `sublayerTransform` property seems a perfect fit.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0/self.zoomValue, 1.0/self.zoomValue);

    self.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(transform);
}
```

Comment: Cool, thats defo worth a go. Do you know if it will be better for performance than my current implementation?

Comment: Tried it - the performance is definitely better, but its not quite doing the same thing as before. Before each view was scaled about its centre point (which made them stay in the same place relative to the map) now this doesn't happen - they stay in the same place relative to each other, which is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @Gaz_Edge I _think_ `sublayerTransform` affects the layer's bounds instead of setting sublayers' transformation. Then, I guess, my suggestion won't work for you. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ok - thanks for trying anyway. Any other ideas on the best way to do this? Im really just trying to future proof my code for performance. Want to make sure im doing things in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about creating an intermediate subview holding your 100 subviews?
You could just set the transform for the intermediate subview and you would be done.

Comment: I did think about that. I need to keep the subviews in the same position in the superview. I'm applying the scale transform.

Comment: The views I want to transform are pins on a map. When I zoom in I want them to stay the same size on screen and over the same point on the map.

Comment: Have you tried removing `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` from your view autoresize mask?

Comment: Try and think of the pins on the map. I need to scale them down when I zoom in, and keep them in the same place. Auto resizing is too basic no?