# Alternative to self.view to get frame of view?

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to make everything on a view controller scaled smaller but still centered in the middle, but I have two containers within the view controller I am trying to scale down and self.view changes the frames of these containers too. Is there a way I can simply scale down everything or just change the size of the view controller that has the two containers in it but not the two containers? Thanks!

Comment: I think this is duplicated with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153379/transform-all-subviews

Comment: Also please edit the question title, it's a little misleading